# react return multiple of node

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to return multiples of a node (not sure if this is the right term).

The idea is a rating system. If the rating is 5 then I would like to return 5 `<FontAwesome name='star' />`

This is actually on a resume page.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';


class Summary extends Component {
    dot = 'circle';

    mapSummaryToLi(summaries) {
        return summaries.map((point, index) =>
            <li key={index}>{point}</li>
        )
    }

    mapSkillsToList(skills) {
        return skills.map((skill, index) =>
            <li key={index}>{skill.name}&nbsp;{this.numberToDots(skill.level)} </li>)
    }

    numberToDots(level) {
        let total = new Array(parseInt(level));

        return total.map(() => <FontAwesome name={this.dot}/>)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section id="summary">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-8">
                        <div className="heading">
                            Summary of Qualifications
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            {this.mapSummaryToLi(this.props.summary)}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                        <div className="heading">
                            Skills
                        </div>
                        <ul id="skills">
                            {this.mapSkillsToList(this.props.skills)}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

As this only returns black spaces. I feel quite stuck. The `skill.level` is an integer coming from JSON.

I am looking for a way to return multiple of a node. I.E.

```
return <FontAwesome name="circle"> * 3 //I know this does not work.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with `let total = new Array(parseInt(level))` and `return total.map(() => <FontAwesome name={this.dot}/>)` since the `total` array contains 5 `undefined` values. maybe try using `lodash`'s `.range` instead of `new Array()` ? http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html

Comment: @oobgam Yes that was my next solution but I was looking for a more general answer to the problem. How do I return a finite number of elements based off of an Integer prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `new Array(x)` creates an array of length `x`, the array doesn't actually contain any values. The `.map` callback won't be called for "holes". See:

```js
console.log(Array(5).map(x => 42));
```

You can do the following instead:

```
return Array.from(Array(5), () => <FontAwesome name={this.dot}/>);
```

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(5), x => 42));
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Is there a better way to handle this type of scenario? Needing a specific amount of something and passing an Int as a prop?

Comment: Most of the time I think you have a list of items that need to be rendered, so that's easy. But if need to render something `n` times, there is not much else you can do I guess.